# Can't generate toSring() in Java Eclipse oxygen

Tags: tostring

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ayMb74zcPmlMghMxK9mx2_tRVvfVBje1/view?usp=sharing

What should I do?
In java Eclipse Oxygen

I have already edited a link to not suspicious.

Comment: I don't think anyone will be clicking on that suspicious-looking link. You need to post your code or image inline as part of the question.

Comment: Vasan's comment still applies.